# Example of an algebra which is not affine?

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone suggest me an example of $K$-algebra $A$ which is not affine? Here $K$ is a field. 
Thanks!

Comment: In your context, what is an affine algebra?

Comment: Definition: (Affine Algebra) An affine algebra is a commutative algebra $A$  over a field $K$, such that $R=K[a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n]$ for suitable $a_i$'s $\in A$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The rational function field $K(T)$.